# Drupal 7 - Images from IMCE (+Wysiwyg) showing as [img]link[/img]

Tags: image, drupal-7, tinymce, wysiwyg

When I'm uploading images through TinyMCE image panel it is available in edit mode preview. But in view mode there is no image just [img]link/to/image[/img] metatags. What is wrong? I'd enabled filter "Convert Media tags to markup" but has no luck.

Using WYSIWYG editor with TinyMCE + IMCE + Media modules.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:
go to yourdomain.com/admin/config/content/wysiwyg
click edit next to the editor you use , then expand "Buttons and Plugins" and **Uncheck** "BBCode" , then save,

This is worked for me, and I hope it helps you.